# Creating and assigning values to a variable in Scala template

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have not been able to solve this specific case from the examples provided in the documentation.

I create a Result:

```
    Customer customer = new Customer("James");
    Order[] orders = new Order[2];
    orders[0] = new Order("Apple");
    orders[1] = new Order("Orange");
    Content html = views.html.template.render(customer, orders);
    return ok(html);
```

And my template is:

```
@(customer: Customer, orders: Array[Order])

<h1>Welcome @customer.name!</h1>

<ul> 
    @for(order <- orders) {
      <li>@order.name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Now I want to add a Boolean variable in the template, then iterate through the orders, and if Apple appears in the orders, I want to set the created variable to true.

Basically I need a var that has scope throughout the whole template.

Thank you.

Added some pseudocode.

```
@(customer: Customer, orders: Array[Order])

<h1>Welcome @customer.name!</h1>

**** var containsApple = false;

<ul> 
    @for(order <- orders) {
      <li>@order.name</li>

      **** if order.name == "apple"
      ****   containsApple = true;

    }
</ul>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11289347/136363 Perhaps if you told us what you're trying to achieve (i.e. what you need the `boolean` for), we could help find an alternative route to your goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely move this logic into controller to avoid spaghetti code. Otherwise you can declare a new variable like this: [Declare variable in a Play2 scala template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031146/declare-variable-in-a-play2-scala-template)

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for play templates, but in regular Scala this would be:

```
val containsApple = orders.exists(_.name == "apple")
```

No need for a `var` or any other form of scary mutability.

Comment: It looks like the controller method is actually written in Java.

Comment: Sure... But the controller ain't